# Why export env within tmux fails

Tags: environment-variables, tmux

Command like the following:

```
ssh hostname 'tmux new -d "export A=whatever && echo $A && while true; do date; sleep 1; done"'
```

After executing this command, ssh to hostname and attach to the tmux session, you'll see that `$A` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` sign should be escaped.

```
ssh hostname 'tmux new -d "export A=whatever && echo \$A && while true; do date; sleep 1; done"'
```